# what image does fastboot -w flashall flashes?

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, images, factory-image

Take Google Pixel as example. I managed to do a full APSO+kernel build and the resulting binaries is located at out/target/product/marlin as the following:

```
boot.img
ramdisk.img <-- I believe this is part of boot.img?
ramdisk-recovery.img <-- I believe this is part of boot.img?
system.img
system_other.img
userdata.img
vendor.img
```

**Question 1**:
If I perform a `fastboot -w flashall` which of the binaries will be flashed into a phone?

Furthermore, when i inspect the [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/images) I found the following files:

```
bootloader-marlin-8996-012001-1608281716.img
radio-marlin-8996-012511-1609081444.img 
image-marlin-nde63j.zip <--- contain basically all images from build plus many more
```

**Question 2:** Looking at the factory image, is obvious not all images can be obtained by build. I will assume that bootloader and radio are close source, and many more in the zip files such as modem.img, keymaster.img ...etc, are there any documents regarding to all these images?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/fastboot/fastboot.cpp#334 // You could  find it yourself if you simply enter fastboot command.